# cronjob time 13 * * * *

Tags: cron

It surely going to sound like a silly question but

i wanted to have a confirm about that crontab time

```
13 * * * *
```

does it really mean to launch at the 13th minute of every hr of every day of every week and so on? Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend [CronSandbox](http://www.cronsandbox.com) to try it out, better to be safe than sorry.

The output there confirms you're right as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. To avoid such questions in the future, it is useful to have such header in your crontab file:

```
#minute (0-59),
#|      hour (0-23),
#|      |       day of the month (1-31),
#|      |       |       month of the year (1-12),
#|      |       |       |       day of the week (0-6 with 0=Sunday).
#|      |       |       |       |       commands

13      *       *       *       *       command
```

Comment: Thankyou for the nice memo-header. I was just in a doubt